# Prove that if $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=b$ then $b=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that if $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=b$ then $b=0$

I think this is true but don't know how to go about proving it?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim(f(x)e^x)/e^x=\lim(f(x)e^x)'/(e^x)'=\lim e^x(f(x)+f'(x))/e^x$ $=\lim(f(x)+f'(x))=b+\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$.

Comment: I think you have to suppose that $f$ is monotonous... Take $f(x)=\frac{sin(x^3)}{x}$

Answer (score 2):

It follows by a L'Hôpital slick trick: $\ $ if $\rm\ f + f\:'\!\to L\ $ as $\rm\ x\to\infty\ $ then $\rm\ f\to L,\ f\:'\!\to 0,\ $ since

$$\rm \lim_{x\to\infty}\ f(x)\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ f(x)}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (f(x)+f'(x))}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\ (f(x)+f'(x)) $$

This L'Hospital rule trick achieved some noteriety due to the fact that the problem appeared in Hardy's classic calculus texbook *A Course of Pure Mathematics*, but with a less elegant solution. For example, see Landau; Jones: [A Hardy Old Problem,](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689813) Math. Magazine 56 (1983) 230-232.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem.

Try and prove it with this hint:
For any $n$ we have $f(n+1)-f(n) = f'(\xi_n)$ for some $x \in (n,n+1)$.

Spoiler:

> Taking limits gives $\lim_n (f(n+1)-f(n)) = 0 = \lim_n f'(\xi_n) = b$. Hence $b=0$.